Does infinite loop contributes to Decision making
while True:
    num = int(input())
    
    if num < 0:
        print("a")
        break
    
    if num % 2 == 0:
        if num % 3 == 0:
            print("d")
        else:
            print(num)
    else:
        print(num)

for the above code below what will be the cyclomatic complexity? Will it be 4 not 5 because it is an infinite loop and the while loop does not contribute to any decision making therefore it is considered as 1 node with the input?
If I am wrong then can you kindly explain?

hi Feio, this probably  belongs in [cs.se], although, please check out their guidelines before posting a question.
